# Naming Python loggers

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

In Django, I've got loggers all over the place, currently with hard-coded names.

For module-level logging (i.e., in a module of view functions) I have the urge to do this.

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

For class-level logging (i.e., in a class `__init__` method) I have the urge to do this.

```
self.log = logging.getLogger("%s.%s" % (
    self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__))
```

I'm looking for second opinions before I tackle several dozen occurrences of `getLogger("hard.coded.name")`.

Will this work?  Anyone else naming their loggers with the same unimaginative ways?

Further, should I break down and write a class decorator for this log definition?

Comment: I'm curious: why would you want class-level loggin?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I typically don't use or find a need for class-level loggers, but I keep my modules at a few classes at most. A simple:

```
import logging
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

At the top of the module and subsequent:

```
LOG.info('Spam and eggs are tasty!')
```

from anywhere in the file typically gets me to where I want to be. This avoids the need for `self.log` all over the place, which tends to bother me from both a put-it-in-every-class perspective and makes me 5 characters closer to 79 character lines that fit.

You could always use a pseudo-class-decorator:

```
>>> import logging
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.log.info('Meh')
... 
>>> def logged_class(cls):
...     cls.log = logging.getLogger('{0}.{1}'.format(__name__, cls.__name__))
... 
>>> logged_class(Foo)
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> f = Foo()
INFO:__main__.Foo:Meh
```

Comment: Interesting approach... I think I spent too long with Java.  Module-level logging may be just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: There is one problem with the usage of `__name__`: When the module is imported somewhere using a relative import, its messages will go to the log using that shorter `__name__`. This is not a problem as long as you avoid these relative imports, which are bad style anyway (as stated in the python FAQ)

Answer (score 3):

For class level logging, as an alternative to a pseudo-class decorator, you could use a metaclass to make the logger for you at class creation time...

```
import logging

class Foo(object):
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
            type.__init__(name, bases, attrs)
            cls.log = logging.getLogger('%s.%s' % (attrs['__module__'], name))
    def __init__(self):
        self.log.info('here I am, a %s!' % type(self).__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    foo = Foo()
```

Comment: I had to change `type.__init__(...)` to `object.__init__(...)`, or there will be an error under python 2.7: `descriptor '__init__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'str'`. But I cannot get this method to work under python 3.x.

Comment: I figured it out. To get this method also working for python 3.x, I need to write the metaclass separately, and use hack like `logging_metaclass_hack = logging_metaclass("logging_metaclass_hack", (object, ), {})` and inherit to Foo.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like it will work, except that `self` won't have a `__module__` attribute; its class will.  The class-level logger call should look like:

```
self.log = logging.getLogger( "%s.%s" % ( self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__ ) )
```

Comment: Are you sure self won't have a __module__ attribute? I tried it and it seemed to have one.

Comment: self does have a __module__ attribute.

Comment: Strange...

    >>> from datetime import date
    >>> d = date.today()
    >>> d.__module__
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '__module__'
    >>> d.__class__.__module__
    'datetime'
    >>>

Comment: Well, that got butchered; apparently you can't put code into a comment on a comment.

Anyway, I looked at datetime to see if an instance had a __module__ attribute and it doesn't look like it does.  Maybe other classes do.

Comment: @Steve: __module__ is probably undefined for C-API instances. Not 100% on that one, but instances of user defined types appear to have it.