# What are some common uses for Python decorators?

Tags: python, decorator

While I like to think of myself as a reasonably competent Python coder, one aspect of the language I've never been able to grok is decorators.

I know what they are (superficially), I've read tutorials, examples, questions on Stack Overflow, and I understand the syntax, can write my own, occasionally use @classmethod and @staticmethod, but it never occurs to me to use a decorator to solve a problem in my own Python code.  I never encounter a problem where I think, "Hmm...this looks like a job for a decorator!"

So, I'm wondering if you guys might offer some examples of where you've used decorators in your own programs, and hopefully I'll have an "A-ha!" moment and *get* them.

Comment: Also, decorators are useful for Memoizing - that is caching a slow-to-compute result of a function.  The decorator can return a function that checks the inputs, and if they have already been presented, return a cached result.

Comment: Note that Python has a built-in decorator, `functools.lru_cache`, which does exactly what Peter said, since Python 3.2, released in February 2011.

Comment: The Contents of the [Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) should give you a good idea of other uses for them.

Answer (score 141):

I use decorators mainly for timing purposes

```
def time_dec(func):

  def wrapper(*arg):
      t = time.clock()
      res = func(*arg)
      print func.func_name, time.clock()-t
      return res

  return wrapper


@time_dec
def myFunction(n):
    ...
```

Comment: Under Unix, `time.clock()` measures CPU time. You might want to use `time.time()` instead if you want to measure wall-clock time.

Comment: Great example! No idea what it does though. An explanation what you are doing there, and how the decorator solves the problem would be very nice.

Comment: Well, it measures the time it takes for `myFunction` to run ...

Comment: `@time_dec` is syntatic sugar for: `myFunction = time_dec(myFunction)`. The rest is standard python

Answer (score 103):

I've used them for synchronization.

```
import functools

def synchronized(lock):
    """ Synchronization decorator """
    def wrap(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def newFunction(*args, **kw):
            lock.acquire()
            try:
                return f(*args, **kw)
            finally:
                lock.release()
        return newFunction
    return wrap
```

As pointed out in the comments, since Python 2.5 you can use a [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement in conjunction with a  [`threading.Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) (or [`multiprocessing.Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) since version 2.6) object to simplify the decorator's implementation to just:

```
import functools

def synchronized(lock):
    """ Synchronization decorator """
    def wrap(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def newFunction(*args, **kw):
            with lock:
                return f(*args, **kw)
        return newFunction
    return wrap
```

Regardless, you then use it like this:

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

@synchronized(lock)
def do_something():
  # etc

@synchronzied(lock)
def do_something_else():
  # etc
```

Basically it just puts `lock.acquire()` / `lock.release()` on either side of the function call.

Comment: Possibly justified, but decorators are inherently confusing, esp. to first-year noobs who come behind you and try to mod your code.  Avoid this with simplicity:  just have do_something() enclose its code in a block under 'with lock:' and everyone can clearly see your purpose.  Decorators are vastly overused by people wanting to seem smart (and many actually are) but then the code comes to mere mortals and gets effed-up.

Comment: @KevinJ.Rice Constraining your code so that 'first-year noobs' can better understand it is terrible practice. Decorator syntax is far easier to read and greatly decouples the code.

Comment: @TaylerJones, code readability is just about my highest priority when writing.  Code is read 7+ times for every time it's modified.  Hard to understand code (for noobs or for experts who are working under time pressure) is technical debt that has to be paid every time someone visits the source tree.

Comment: @TaylerJones One of the most important tasks for a programmer is to deliver clarity.

Comment: @JDOaktown one important task for programmers is to actually be able to understand simple concepts of the languages they work with..

Comment: @TaylerJones Also, undecorated code is much easier to debug hence finding bugs is easier.

Answer (score 81):

I use decorators for type checking parameters which are passed to my Python methods via some RMI. So instead of repeating the same parameter counting, exception-raising mumbo-jumbo again and again.

For example, instead of:

```
def myMethod(ID, name):
    if not (myIsType(ID, 'uint') and myIsType(name, 'utf8string')):
        raise BlaBlaException() ...
```

I just declare:

```
@accepts(uint, utf8string)
def myMethod(ID, name):
    ...
```

and `accepts()` does all the work for me.

Comment: For anyone interested, there's an implementation of `@accepts` in PEP 318.

Comment: I think there is typo.. the first method should be accepts.. you declared both as "myMethod"

Comment: @DevC No, it doesn't look like a typo. Since that's clearly not an implementation of "accepts(..)", and here "accepts(..)" does the work that would otherwise be done by the two lines at the start of "myMethod(..)" — that's the only interpretation that fits.

Comment: Sorry for the bump, I just wanted to point out that checking for the type of the arguments passed and raise a TypeError otherwise is considered a bad practice because it's not going to accept e.g. a int if it checks only for floats, and because normally the code itself should adapt for different kinds of values passed for maximum flexibility.

Comment: now there is no need to this since type annotation is available in python 3.x +

Comment: The recommended way to do type checking in Python is via the built-in [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function, as it's done in the PEP 318 [implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples) of the decorator. Since its `classinfo` argument can be one or more types, using it would also mitigate @Gustavo6046's (valid) objections. Python also has an [`Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#module-numbers) abstract base class, so very generic tests like `isinstance(42, numbers.Number)`are possible.

Comment: is there a difference between @accepts, type annotation / hints, and isinstance() ?

Answer (score 53):

Decorators are used for anything that you want to transparently "wrap" with additional functionality.

Django uses them for wrapping ["login required" functionality on view functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/?from=olddocs#the-login-required-decorator), as well as for [registering filter functions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters).

You can use class decorators for [adding named logs to classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401277/naming-python-loggers#402471).

Any sufficiently generic functionality that you can "tack on" to an existing class or function's behavior is fair game for decoration.

There's also a [discussion of use cases on the Python-Dev newsgroup](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-April/044132.html) pointed to by [PEP 318 -- Decorators for Functions and Methods](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#background).

Comment: Cherrypy uses @cherrypy.expose to keep straight which functions are public and which are hidden functions. That was my first introduction and I got used to it form there.

Answer (score 33):

For nosetests, you can write a decorator that supplies a unit test function or method with several sets of parameters:

```
@parameters(
   (2, 4, 6),
   (5, 6, 11),
)
def test_add(a, b, expected):
    assert a + b == expected
```

Answer (score 24):

The Twisted library uses decorators combined with generators to give the illusion that an asynchronous function is synchronous.  For example:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def asyncf():
    doStuff()
    yield someAsynchronousCall()
    doStuff()
    yield someAsynchronousCall()
    doStuff()
```

Using this, code that would have been broken up into a ton of little callback functions can be written quite naturally as a single block, making it a lot easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 19):

One obvious use is for logging, of course:

```
import functools

def log(logger, level='info'):
    def log_decorator(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*a, **kwa):
            getattr(logger, level)(fn.__name__)
            return fn(*a, **kwa)
        return wrapper
    return log_decorator

# later that day ...
@log(logging.getLogger('main'), level='warning')
def potentially_dangerous_function(times):
    for _ in xrange(times): rockets.get_rocket(NUCLEAR=True).fire()
```

Answer (score 12):

I use them mainly for debugging (wrapper around a function that prints its arguments and result) and verification (e.g. to check if an argument is of correct type or, in the case of web application, if the user has sufficient privileges to call a particular method).

Answer (score 6):

Decorators are used either to define a function's properties or as boilerplate that alters it; it's possible but counter-intuitive for them to return completely different functions.  Looking at the other responses here, it seems like one of the most common uses is to limit the scope of some other process - be it logging, profiling, security checks, etc.

CherryPy uses object-dispatching to match URLs to objects and, eventually, methods.  Decorators on those methods signal whether or not CherryPy is even *allowed* to use those methods.  For example, adapted from [the tutorial](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyTutorial):

```
class HelloWorld:

    ...

    def secret(self):
        return "You shouldn't be here."

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: This is not true.  A decorator can completely change the behavior of a function.

Comment: Okay.  But how often does a decorator "completely change the behavior of a function?"  From what I've seen, when they're not used to specify properties, they're just used for boilerplate code.

I've edited my response.

Answer (score 6):

I used them recently, while working on social networking web application. For Community/Groups, I was supposed to give membership authorization to create new discussion and reply to a message you have to be the member of that particular group. So, I wrote a decorator `@membership_required` and put that where I required in my view.

Answer (score 6):

I am using the following decorator for making a function threadsafe. It makes the code more readable. It is almost similar to the one proposed by John Fouhy but the difference is that one work on a single function and that there is no need to create a lock object explicitely.

```
def threadsafe_function(fn):
    """decorator making sure that the decorated function is thread safe"""
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def new(*args, **kwargs):
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            r = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            lock.release()
        return r
    return new

class X:
    var = 0

    @threadsafe_function     
    def inc_var(self):
        X.var += 1    
        return X.var
```

Comment: Does this mean each function, so decorated, has its own lock?

Comment: @grieve yes, every time the decorator is used (called) it creates a new lock object for the function/method being decorated.

Comment: That's really dangerous. The method inc_var() is "threadsafe" in that only one person can call it at a time. That said, since the method operates on member variable "var" and presumably other methods may also operate on member variable "var" and those accesses are not threadsafe since the lock is not shared. Doing things this way gives the user of class X a false sense of security.

Comment: Thats not thread safe until single lock is used.

Answer (score 2):

Decorator can be used to easily create function method variables.

```
def static_var(varname, value):
    '''
    Decorator to create a static variable for the specified function
    @param varname: static variable name
    @param value: initial value for the variable
    '''
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    return decorate

@static_var("count", 0)
def mainCallCount():
    mainCallCount.count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but (apolgies) I have to say WTF - Why would you use this?  It has HUGE potential for confusing people.  Of course, I respect needs for edge-case uses, but you're hitting on a common problem many inexperienced Python devs have - not using classes enough.  That is, just have a simple class var of count, initialize it, and use it.  Noobs tend to write drop-thru (non-class-based code) and try to cope with the lack of class functionality with elaborate workarounds.  Please don't?  Please?  sorry to harp, thank you for your answer, but you've hit a hot-button for me.

Comment: I'd be -1 on this if it showed up as a pull request for me to code review, and so I'm also -1 on this as good python.

Comment: Cute. Silly, but cute. :) I don't mind the occasional function attribute, but they're such a rare thing in typical Python code that if I'm going to use one, I'd rather do so explicitly, rather than hide it under a decorator.

Answer (score 1):

I use this decorator to fix parameter

```
def fill_it(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, int):
        return "wan" + str(arg)
    else:
        try:
            # number present as string
            if str(int(arg)) == arg:
                return "wan" + arg
            else:
                # This should never happened
                raise Exception("I dont know this " + arg)
                print "What arg?"
        except ValueError, e:
            return arg

def fill_wanname(func):
    def wrapper(arg):
        filled = fill_it(arg)
        return func(filled)
    return wrapper

@fill_wanname
def get_iface_of(wanname):
    global __iface_config__
    return __iface_config__[wanname]['iface']
```

this written when I refactor some functions need to passed argument "wanN" but in my old codes, I passed N or 'N' only