# Are Python instance variables thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

OK, check following codes first:

```
class DemoClass():

    def __init__(self):
        #### I really want to know if self.Counter is thread-safe. 
        self.Counter = 0

    def Increase(self):
        self.Counter = self.Counter + 1

    def Decrease(self):
        self.Counter = self.Counter - 1

    def DoThis(self):
        while True:
            Do something

            if A happens:
                self.Increase()
            else:
                self.Decrease()

            time.sleep(randomSecs)

    def DoThat(self):
        while True:
            Do other things

            if B happens:
                self.Increase()
            else:
                self.Decrease()

            time.sleep(randomSecs)

    def ThreadSafeOrNot(self):
        InterestingThreadA = threading.Thread(target = self.DoThis, args = ())
        InterestingThreadA.start()

        InterestingThreadB = threading.Thread(target = self.DoThat, args = ())
        InterestingThreadB.start()
```

I'm facing same situation as above. I really want to know if it's thread-safe for `self.Counter`, well if not, what options do I have? I can only think of `threading.RLock()` to lock this resource, any better idea?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Variables accessed by multiple threads at the same time will lead to race conditions and unwanted behaviours. You must rely on Locks, RLocks, Semaphores, Conditions, Events or Queues.

The following [article](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/) helps to understand the difference between each and when to use them in a multi-threaded environment:

Comment: This does not directly answer the posted question.

Answer (score 32):

Using the instance field `self.Counter` is [thread safe or "atomic"](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe) ([or here](https://superfastpython.com/thread-atomic-operations/)). Reading it or assigning a *single* value - even when it needs 4 bytes in memory, you will never get a half-changed value. But the operation `self.Counter = self.Counter + 1` is not because it reads the value and then writes it - another thread could change the value of the field after it has been read and before it is written back.

So you need to protect the whole operation with a lock.

Since method body is basically the whole operation, you can use a decorator to do this. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/490090/34088

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "the instance field ... is thread safe"?

Comment: @EliBendersky: I guess he means operations like `self.Counter = Value` are thread-safe. Check this article I just found: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm

Comment: Assigning a value is not thread-safe. Say you have self.Counter=1 followed by self.Counter=2 then x=self.Counter. Then x can get 1 or 2 depending on thread switching, which makes assigning a value not thread-safe.

Comment: What I said is that a *single* assignment is atomic (except for 64-bit types). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756536/what-operations-in-java-are-considered-atomic

Comment: How is increment a problem as the instance variable of class exists only within one thread. Is an instance variable shared across threads?

Comment: @variable In the code in the question, the same instance is shared between threads.

Comment: This is the information that I was looking for actually. People who don't know `C`, don't even think about this while mutexing every operation. Still, I'll put an uppercase comment line with this info but I'll remove mutexes from my code to improve performance.

Comment: In your first sentence you link an SO answer for _Java_. How is this relevant for this question?

Answer (score 15):

No, it is not thread safe - the two threads are essentially modifying the same variable simultaneously. And yes, the solution is one of the locking mechanisms in the `threading` module.

BTW, `self.Counter` is an *instance variable*, not a *class variable*.

Comment: I think that only class variable is not thread safe. Instance variables should be thread safe unless the class instance is created globally, and passed to the thread. What do you think?

Comment: @variable because instances can be passed to different thread, your point dosn't make sense. Things are or aren't thread safe regardless of their implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`self.Counter` is an instance variable, so each thread has a copy.

If you declare the variable outside of `__init__()`, it will be a class variable.
All instances of the class will share that instance.

Comment: Surely multiple threads can access the same instance of an object?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Be very careful with that. It can add quite a bit of complexity. You may have to do some form of locking.

Comment: @AustinHenley: yes, that's the point.  The OP wanted to know whether instance variables were thread-safe or not.

Comment: I think that only class variable is not thread safe. Instance variables should be thread safe unless the class instance is created globally, and passed to the thread. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The [Atomos](https://github.com/maxcountryman/atomos) library provides atomic (thread-safe) wrappers for Python primitives and objects, including atomic counters.  It uses single-writer/multiple-reader locks.