# web2py - is this thread-safe

Tags: python, web2py

I'm not really that knowledgeable about thread-safe vs non-thread-safe operations but am wondering if a problem I'm seeing might be because of that.

In my modules directory I've created a module that has a class defined.

Then in db.py I have an _after_insert trigger like so:

```
db.workorder._after_insert.append(lambda s,f: workorderAfterInsert(s,f))
```

In my _after_insert trigger I'm instantiating the class from my module like this:

```
import workorder.sequencer as sequencer

workorderId = id
wo = db.workorder(workorderId)

sequencer = sequencer.Sequencer(workorder_id=workorderId, db=db)
sequencer.build_bom()
sequencer.sequence()
sequencer.save_sequenced_workorder()

db.commit()
```

I'm not sure how to describe it, but I'm seeing random errors popping up in the execution of sequencer.sequence().  My only thought at this point is that there are thread-safe or concurrency issues going on.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me whether or not this is safe (or wise).  Any input would be appreciated.

-Jim

Comment: What is `sequencer` and where/how is `db` defined? Please show more of the relevant code.

Comment: Can't really tell if you do not show how the code interacts.

Comment: @Anthony - Sequencer is just a class I've written and stored in the modules directory.  If you think it is relevant I can post here.

Comment: I just found this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309902/are-python-instance-variables-thread-safe   I think my problem may be that I had all my variables as 'class' variables instead of instances variables (which was what I thought I was getting).  I've implemented the change and will see if this works better.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had my variables defined as class variables instead of instance variables.  Changed that up and now it all works.