# Django Class-Based View: Would a lock be reduntant in this example?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-multithreading, django-class-based-views

```
class MyView(ListView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        a_class = MyClass()
        context['...'] = a_class.is_a_lock_reduntant_here()
        return context


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def is_a_lock_reduntant_here(self):
        return self.counter += 1
```

[The above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310128/2996101) is not a [thread safe](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) practice and I would normally use a lock.

However, [django states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#specification) that:

> Each request served by a class-based view has an independent state;
>   therefore, it is safe to store state variables on the instance (i.e.,
>   self.foo = 3 is a thread-safe operation).

I do not completely understand the above quotation because storing state variables **is** an [atomic operation](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#atomic-operations).

In my case I read and replace at the same time. The same quotation, reads that each view has an "independent state".

Is it safe to consider the use of a lock redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This instance cannot possibly be shared across threads, so there is no need for a lock here.

As the documentation you link to shows, each request is a thread-safe operation. As part of that, the ListView is instantiated for each request, and its `get_context_data` is called within that request. That means that the instantiation of MyClass is also only ever within a single thread.