# Do I need synchronization for immutable objects?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have an immutable object (a `float`) that is "written" by one thread and read by another one. Do I need synchronization for that?

```
class Foo:
   def __init(self):
      self._bar = None

   def writeAttribute(self, newValue):
      self._bar = newValue

   def readAttribute(self):
      return self._bar
```

Note that `writeAttribute` and `readAttribute` are called from different threads for the same instance. My understanding is that `readAttribute` returns a "reference" either to the old value or the new one, but nothing in between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Python instance variables thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309902/are-python-instance-variables-thread-safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CPython (the one from `python.org`) the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL") ensures that *only one thread at a time is executing Python bytecodes*. Also, threads can be preempted in between bytecodes, but not "inside" them. That means bytecodes are *atomic*.

That means that every action that takes a single bytecode is thread-safe as a *side-effect* of the GIL.

Consider the following code, were the `dis` module is used to see bytecodes for a function:

```
In [2]: bar = 3.14
Out[2]: 3.14

In [3]: def modify(new):
   ...:     global bar
   ...:     bar = new
   ...:     

In [4]: dis.dis(modify)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (new)
              2 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (bar)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Assigning a new value to the global `bar` takes only a single `STORE_GLOBAL` bytecode. So that should be thread-safe, in the sense that `bar` always points to an object. Its value is never undetermined.

Of note; it doesn't matter that a `float` object is immutable. The *reference* to that object (`bar` in the example) *is* mutable. It is that reference that you want to keep defined and unambiguous.

Second, instead of a getter/setter method in your `class Foo` I would propose that you use [@property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator. It is considered more Pythonic.

**Edit**

See also the FAQ: [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe)

**Edit2**

Of course: when in doubt, use e.g. a `Lock`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the immutability of the object does not matter here, only the validity of the reference.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about global variables, but for their case, I don't think it's quite so safe. If you do `dis.dis(Foo().writeAttribute)` (which I think would be better anyway, instead of making up something different), you'll likely see a single `STORE_ATTR`, which I think *isn't* safe (if they write a `__setattr__` method they could execute arbitrary further Python code during its execution).

Comment: @KellyBundy the FAQ explicitly states that: *Each bytecode instruction and therefore all the C implementation code reached from each instruction is therefore atomic from the point of view of a Python program.* So I guess that a `__settatr__` would not be a single `STORE_ATTR` bytecode.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `__settatr__ ` not being a single bytecode. It's not a bytecode at all.

Comment: @KellyBundy What I mean is that a setter method would indeed have multiple bytecodes. But the *actual assignment* could still be a single bytecode.

Comment: Right, but their threads aren't executing the *actual assignment*, they're calling the `writeAttribute` method.

Comment: Yes, but as long as the *actual assignment* is atomic, then at no point `self._bar` would de undetermined.