# Why are decorators useful?

Tags: python, python-decorators

So I read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python) about decorators, but I still don't understand **when** decorators are useful.

Consider a piece of code defining a function `f`, and then calling it multiple times. For some reason we want `f` to do some extra work. So we have 2 ways to do it:

1. define a new function `g` which calls `f`, and does the extra work needed. Then in the main code, replace all calls to `f` by calls to `g`
2. define a decorator `g`, and edit the code to add `@g` before calls to `f`

In the end, they both achieve the same result and the advantage of 2) over 1) is not obvious to me. What am i missing?

Comment: The day you need them is when you'll actually find its usefulness.

Comment: Decorators are just syntactic sugar. Anywhere you want to wrap a function or attach side effects to a function, decorators are useful.

Comment: You can find a lot of good feedback here I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/489754/463678

Comment: Take a look at the [`@property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) for an example of a standard library decorator. Or the [`@functools.total_ordering` class decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering). Or the [`@contextlib.contextmanager()` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

Comment: Decorators are just a design pattern. Get more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some common uses for Python decorators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489720/what-are-some-common-uses-for-python-decorators)

Comment: There’s an important thing you’ve missed: if you want to wrap a function `f` with a decorator `g`, you only have to add `@g` *once*—at the declaration of `f`—not every time `f` is used. Therefore option (2) will only ever involve one code change, while (1) could mean dozens.

Comment: Its syntactic sugar that makes it easier to read and maintain. Wrapping with functions is just more clutter this way you get to write it in a way that suits the intenion better. All of object oriented notation is syntactic sugar and we find it usefull.

Comment: Technically, you don't need Python, since there were languages before Python that did everything Python can do. However, some people find that writing in Python makes it easier to do their job. Decorators are similar; sure you can just use your existing tools (defining a new function), but a decorator might be able to solve exactly the same functional requirements with code that is faster to develop or easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a lot of functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, ... and you want a regular way to make the same change to all of them to do the same extra work.

That's what you're missing and it's why decorators are useful. That is to say, functions that take a function and return a modified version of it.

The decorator `@` syntax is "just" for convenience. It lets you decorate the function as it is defined:

```
@decorated
def foo():
    # several lines
```

instead of somewhere after the function definition:

```
def foo():
    # several lines

foo = decorated(foo)
```

In fact of course the latter code is pretty horrible, since it means that by looking at the first definition of `foo` in the source, you don't see the same `foo` that users will call. So without the syntax, decorators wouldn't be so valuable because you'd pretty much always end up using different names for the decorated and undecorated functions.

Comment: What's the difference between that and calling decorated() as a function? (besides the annotation of course)