# Python: "@" followed by a function -> What does it stand for?

Tags: python, special-characters, keyword, semantics, notation

I'm currently learning Python and I came across a notation I was wondering about:

```
import taskmanager as tm

#........

@tm.task(str)
def feat(folder):
    BLA BLA BLA ...
```

the code is a small excerpt from https://github.com/kfrancoi/phd-retailreco/blob/master/libraries/plsa/example_plsa.py (the file contains several more notations using the `@` sign). 
Is this a common notation in python and what does it mean? Or is this only a notation used in this special case with the taskmanager or what!?

I tried my best looking this up on google but it's though to find as the @-sign is stripped out in my search (too short, special character). Same happens here on Stackoverflow.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: **AS I DESCRIBED IN THE QUESTION** I could **NOT** find a related question as the @-sign is stripped out and didn't know what to look for otherwise (in this case, for decorator which is completely NEW to me...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This a decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), defined by the [PEP 318](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). Extract of the glossary:

> A function returning another function, usually applied as a function transformation using the `@wrapper` syntax. Common examples for decorators are `classmethod()` and `staticmethod()`.
>
> The decorator syntax is merely syntactic sugar, the following two function definitions are semantically equivalent:
>
> ```
> def f(...):
>     ...
> f = staticmethod(f)
>
> @staticmethod
> def f(...):
>     ...
> ```
>
> The same concept exists for classes, but is less commonly used there. See the documentation for function definitions and class definitions for more about decorators.

Related: [What are some common uses for Python decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489720/what-are-some-common-uses-for-python-decorators)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Again: I really do not understand that people downvote the question. **AS I DESCRIBED IN THE QUESTION** I could NOT found a related question as the @-sign is stripped out and didn't know what to look for otherwise (in this case, for *decorator* which is completely NEW to me...). Thanks thuogh!

Comment: You could have searched with *arobase* instead of `@` :-)

Comment: Haha sure, completely new word for me... but nevermind, you even answered, thanks!