# Removing infinity values of a function using exception handling, *args, and **kwargs

Tags: python-2.7, exception, args, keyword-argument, gradient-descent

I'm currently working through the book *Data Science from Scratch* by Joel Grus, and I've run across a function that I don't really understand:

```py
def safe(f):
    def safe_f(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return float('inf')
    return safe_f
```

The safe function is called within a Gradient Descent algorithm to remove infinity values.

```py
def minimize_batch(target_fn, gradient_fn, theta_0, tolerance=0.000001):
    step_sizes = [100, 10, 1, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]

    theta = theta_0
    target_fn = safe(target_fn)
    value = target_fn(theta)

    while True:
        gradient = gradient_fn(theta)
        next_thetas = [step(theta, gradient, -step_size) for step_size in     step_sizes]
        next_theta = min(next_thetas, key=target_fn)
        next_value = target_fn(next_theta)

        if abs(value - next_value) < tolerance:
            return theta
        else:
            theta, value = next_theta, next_value
```

I get the gist of what safe is doing, but I don't understand *how* it's doing it.  For example, how does safe evaluate target_fn if there are no inputs for target_fn? What is safe doing such that it knows how to remove infinity values?

Gradient Descent aside, would this safe function work on a crazy functions that was undefined at uncountably many places?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's removing infinity values to me. It looks like it's _adding_ infinity values, in place of raising an exception. For instance, the unsafe version of `return 1 / x` raises a `ZeroDivisionError` when x is zero; the safe-decorated version does not raise an exception, instead returning infinity.

Comment: It might help you look up information on this if you know that `safe` is a **decorator** function, and that `f` is accessible inside `safe_f` via a **closure**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help you to understand if we replace the variable names step by step:

```
target_fn = safe(target_fn)
```

means that `f` in `safe` is `target_fn`:

```
def safe(target_fn):
    def safe_f(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return target_fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return float('inf')
    return safe_f
```

and:

```
target_fn = safe_f
```

i.e. we replace the function originally bound to `target_fn` with the function `safe_f` we just created in the **decorator function** `safe`, retaining access to the original as `f`, via a **closure**.

So the arguments are passed through `*args, **kwargs` (see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761)):

```
next_value = target_fn(next_theta)
```

gets resolved to:

```
def safe_f(next_theta):
    try:
        return target_fn(next_theta)
    except:
        return float('inf')
```

i.e. either return the result from calling the original `target_fn` with the argument `next_theta` or, if any errors occur when doing so, `float('inf')`.

> would this `safe` function work on a crazy functions that was undefined at uncountably many places?

As it uses `*args, **kwargs` you can use it to wrap *any* function, and it will quietly suppress *any* error raised by the function and return `float('inf')` instead - this won't always be desirable, though! There are many other uses for decorator functions, which are often applied using `@decorator` syntax (e.g. for *class* and *static methods* and *properties* on classes); see e.g. [What are some common uses for Python decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/489720/3001761)