# How to stop sql logging in debug mode?

Tags: django, debugging, logging

How do I run django in debug=True without being bombarded by the sql logging?

Being forced to squint through all this noise is making it rather hard to see my debug messages....

```
[Thu Jul 28 19:56:27 2011] [error] DEBUG:(0.000) SELECT `django_session`.`session_key`, `django_session`.`session_data`, `django_session`.`expire_date` FROM `django_session` WHERE (`django_session`.`session_key` = foobar  AND `django_session`.`expire_date` > 2011-07-28 19:56:27 ); args=('foobar', u'2011-07-28 19:56:27')
[Thu Jul 28 19:56:27 2011] [error] DEBUG:(0.000) SELECT `Users`.`id`, `Users`.`auth_id`, `Users`.`username`, `Users`.`pwhash`, `Users`.`first_name`, `Users`.`last_name`, `Users`.`email`, `Users`.`notes`, `Users`.`force_password_change`, `Users`.`deleted`, `Users`.`deleted_username` FROM `Users` WHERE (`Users`.`deleted` = False  AND `Users`.`id` = 2 ); args=(False, 2)
[Thu Jul 28 19:56:27 2011] [error] DEBUG:(0.000) SELECT `Auths`.`id`, `Auths`.`developer_id`, `Auths`.`application_id` FROM `Auths` WHERE `Auths`.`id` = 2 ; args=(2,)
[Thu Jul 28 19:56:27 2011] [error] DEBUG:(0.000) SELECT `Auths`.`id`, `Auths`.`developer_id`, `Auths`.`application_id` FROM `Auths` WHERE `Auths`.`id` = 2 ; args=(2,)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Django 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) this can be done rather simply with the inclusion of logging.  In summary the way I do it is very similar to the docs and keep the focus of logging on my application.  My settings.py file currently looks like this.

```
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'apps': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

If you are using an older version of Django you can setup logging by using filters (Yes you [can do this in 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-filters) too.)  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters) SO post should provide you with what you need to get going.

**Edit Update**

Again following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) which gives an example combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters) post should get you where you need to go.

1. Add in a `django` handler and propagate it down the chain..
2. Add in a `django.db.backends` which doesn't propagate but raise the noise floor to ERROR

I don't think there is anything else?

HTH

Comment: Yeah 1.3; better but not ideal: are we not able to isolate them, but have to raise the log level for all 'django' messages to "warning"?

Comment: Actually you can - look into propagate.  Basically what you want to do is to only log the django.x.y.z you want.  What is it you are looking to do?