# Python Log Level with an additional verbosity depth

Tags: python, logging

I would like to extend the existing `logging.LEVEL` mechanics so that I have the option of switching between different logging levels such as `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `ERROR` etc. but also define a `depth` for each of the levels.

For example, let's assume that the logging level is set to `logging.DEBUG`. All of the `log.DEBUG()` calls will be visible.

```
log.debug('Limit event has occurred.')
```

So I get:

```
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) Limit event has occurred.
```

What I am after, is passing an extra depth level to the `log.debug()` call so that I can control how much of detail is printed in the `DEBUG` message, not entirely *enabling* or *disabling* the DEBUG level but controlling how much information the **debug** message will carry. So in all cases we see the debug message but in some instances, it is less detailed and on some occasions more information is included.

For example:

```
log.debug('Limit event has occurred.', verbosity=1)
log.debug('The following user has caused the limit event: %s' % (user), verbosity=3)
log.debug('The following files have been affected: %s' % [list_of_files], verbosity=7)
```

So when the logging level is set to `DEBUG` and the global verbosity is set to `GLOBAL_VERBOSITY=1` we will get this:

```
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) Limit event has occurred.
```

And if the global verbosity is set to `GLOBAL_VERBOSITY=4` we will get this:

```
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) Limit event has occurred.
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) The following user has caused the limit event: xpr
```

And if the global verbosity is set to `GLOBAL_VERBOSITY=9` we will get all of the details:

```
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) Limit event has occurred.
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) The following user has caused the limit event: xpr
[2016-10-08 10:07:29,807] <__main__> {myApp:test_condition_info:93} (DEBUG) The following files have been affected: ['inside.ini', 'render.so']
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Looking at my question right now and it almost feels like having a main debug level with a value of `10` which will be used as `log.debug()` and then having a set of custom debug levels with values of `11-19` called `log.debugA()` to `log.debugI()` for different levels of detail, could be a possible solution. But I would like to solve this in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just use the more fine grained logging levels? `DEBUG` is just a wrapper for level 10. You can use

```
Logger.log(10, "message")
```

to log at debug level and then

```
Logger.log(9, "message")
```

which won't show up at debug level, but will if you do

```
Logger.setLevel(9)
```

If you're dead set on doing it the other way, you should look at 'filters'.

[logging with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging

GLOBAL_VERBOSITY = 1

class LoggingErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
  def filter(self, record):
    if record.__dict__.get("verbosity", 0) > GLOBAL_VERBOSITY:
      print "Log message verbosity is greater than threshold, logging line:{0}".format(record)
      return True
    print "Log message verbosity is lower than threshold, not logging line:{0}".format(record)
    return False

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename="test.log")

logger = logging.getLogger()

filter = LoggingErrorFilter()

logger.addFilter(filter)


def main():
    logger.info("Message 1", extra={"verbosity":3})
    logger.info("Message 2", extra={"verbosity":1})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Well, I think, finding a solution to this problem will provide a more elegant way of setting things up. I really need to solve this :(

Comment: Use 'filters' to add/remove verbosity?

Comment: But how will I pass the extra arguments such as `verbosity=1` etc to the filter? The filter seems to be able to inject contextual information, but all the examples are focusing on information that is generated on the fly: `ip`, `user` etc. There is no example demonstrating a way to pass information to the filter with the message itself.

Comment: You can just pass the 'extra' arguments as **kwargs - then they're available as part of the LogRecord dictionary

Comment: logging constants: `FATAL = 50, ERROR = 40, WARN = 30, INFO = 20, DEBUG = 10, NOTSET = 0`