# python logging: disable messages from specific imported function

Tags: python, logging

I know how to suppress log messages up to a certain log level from an imported module:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("module_name").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

I want to know if it's possible to suppress log messages from only a specific function/class in an imported module (and keep all other messages in the module).

I tried this:

```
logging.getLogger("module_name.function_name").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

but it didn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: Logging has a built in function that should help with this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate

Comment: can you give an example? just to clarify, i cannot change the code inside the imported module.

Comment: I don't think this is possible for a single function. Usually, loggers are defined for an entire module (*e.g.* `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`) and the logger doesn't know who is calling it.

Comment: @Dan I apologise, it didn't have the expected result during testing. Have you considered using a decorator function?

Comment: @Dan did you find a solution or do you still need an answer here? If you do, please provide more information regarding your logging configuration. Do you use a `dictConfig` ? Do you just use it straight out of the box ?

Comment: @Marius Mucenicu I didn't find an answer, I've assumed it's not possible based on Neraste's answer.

Comment: @Dan...well... I can show you a way you can exclude logging messages from a particular function if you're still interested, please provide a more detailed description of how your `logging` is configured.

Comment: @Marius Mucenicu I've looked a bit further and I think I've found a way of doing it based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters... I'll see if I can answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this in the end based on [logging with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters):

Contents of `my_module.py`:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def func1():
    logger.debug('Running func1!')


def func2():
    logger.debug('Running func2!')
```

I want to ignore any messages from `func2`, but keep any messages from `func1`.

Contents of `main.py`:

```
import logging

import my_module

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class IgnoreFunc2(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.funcName == 'func2'


# this relies on knowing the variable name in my_module
my_module.logger.addFilter(IgnoreFunc2())


def main():
    my_module.func1()
    my_module.func2()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:my_module:Running func1!
```