# Add information to every log message in Python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am using Python with logging module and would like to add the socket.hostname() to every log message, I have to run this query every message and can not use

```
name = socket.hostname()
```

and then logging format with the name

I am looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879732/logging-with-filters) example of using logging filter, But what I need here is not a filter, it is a simple manipulation of every log message.

How can I achieve the wanted outcome?

Comment: How about to decorate logging function?

Answer (score 5):

This builds upon the answer by Philippe while using [`dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema). The [contextual filter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#filters-contextual) demonstrated in this answer uses [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to log the current CPU and memory usage percentage in each log message.

Save this file in say `mypackage/util/logging.py`:

```py
"""logging utiliies."""
import logging

from psutil import cpu_percent, virtual_memory


class PsutilFilter(logging.Filter):
    """psutil logging filter."""

    def filter(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
        """Add contextual information about the currently used CPU and virtual memory percentages into the given log record."""
        record.psutil = f"c{cpu_percent():02.0f}m{virtual_memory().percent:02.0f}"  # type: ignore
        return True
```

Note that a filter function didn't work for me; only a filter class worked.

Next, update your logging config dict based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507842/) as below:

```py
LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    ...,
    "filters": {"psutil": {"()": "mypackage.util.logging.PsutilFilter"}},
    "handlers": {"console": {..., "filters": ["psutil"]}},
    "formatters": {
        "detailed": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(psutil)s %(process)x:%(threadName)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)d:%(funcName)s: %(message)s"
        }
    },
}
```

Try logging something, and see sample output such as:

```
2020-05-16 01:06:08,973 INFO c68m51 3c:MainThread:mypackage.mymodule:27:myfunction: This is my log message.
```

In the above message, `c68m51` means 68% CPU and 51% memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

You can use filter to add information to every message :

```
import logging
import socket

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.hostname = socket.gethostname() 
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    levels = (logging.DEBUG, logging.INFO, logging.WARNING, logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)-15s hostname: %(hostname)-15s : %(message)s')
    a1 = logging.getLogger('a.b.c')
    f = ContextFilter()
    a1.addFilter(f)
    a1.debug('A debug message')
```