# issues with python logging.getLogger(__name__)

Tags: python, logging, flask, uwsgi, celery-task

I am trying to get logs from a library that I'm using (PyAPNs). It certainly doesn't work out of the box. I looked at the library code to see what they use for a logger, and they use the logging.getLogger() method.

Pre-existing PyAPNs library logging code:

```
_logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Here is one bad idea that I tried to get it working, but I had no luck:

My Application's code (example bad idea):

```
from apns import APNs

class Notifier():

def __init__(self, logger):

    self.logger = logger
    self.apns_client = APNs(arg_list)
    self.apns_client._logger = self.logger

def send_message:

    ...        
    self.apns_client.gateway_server.send_notification(token, payload, identfier=id)        
    ...
```

This didn't work

The library (send_message) is called from a celery task. All logging works fine within the Notifier class and the celery task, just nothing comes into my logger from within the PyAPNs library.

Can someone help me understand what might be happening here?

Comment: The idea is bad, you shouldn't mess with private members. You can either catch everything with a root logger or possibly get their logger with `getLogger(their_module.__name__)` and configure it appropriately. I assume their logger is not running in a separate process, which is a different story.

Comment: Any recommendations for configuring their logger to log through my class logger? The logger setup is rather extensive and in another area of application code.

Comment: Create a logging handler that forwards messages to your logger and attach it to theirs.

Answer (score 0):

if you want customize log handlers to library's logger, just configure at

1) upper-level loggers (e.g. root logger). As reference from [logging-cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network)

```
rootLogger = logging.getLogger('')
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost',
                    logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
# don't bother with a formatter, since a socket handler sends the event as
# an unformatted pickle
rootLogger.addHandler(socketHandler)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')

# Now, define a couple of other loggers which might represent areas in your
# application:

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')
```

2) Or capture the library's logger and configure it explicitly

```
apns_logger = logging.getLogger(apns.__name__)
apns_logger.addHandler(xxx)
```

3) or use filter to filter out 3rd party module's logger [How can I access the current executing module or class name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275334/what-is-a-correct-way-to-filter-different-loggers-using-python-logging)