# How to put some parts of logging off-the-record in python?

Tags: python, logging

I am using logging library in my code, i want some specific words not to be recorded in the log file. Is there any way to remove them before logging?

```
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(fname, 'w', 'utf-8')],
                    level=logging.DEBUG , format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
```

is there something that i could tell the compiler not to log certain type of error or words for example?

thank you

Comment: To my best understanding of the question, you want to set the `level` to something other than `level=logging.DEBUG`

Comment: Blacklisting loggingmessages like `passwort=123456supersafe890` ?

Comment: A quick forage into SO brought me to this: [what-is-a-correct-way-to-filter-different-loggers-using-python-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275334/what-is-a-correct-way-to-filter-different-loggers-using-python-logging)  - give it a read, maybe you could leverage logger filters to blacklist keywords of messages instead of whitelisting logger by names. No idea.

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's exactly what i need, it logs my TOKEN which i obviously don't want and private user name. i want such words to be filtered.